# Finding 2nd Largest Element in the Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was learning DSA to improve my logic in programming, i was solving this problem to find 2nd largest element in the array using C#. i couldnt do it for first time but idk how a logic clicked in my mind so i tried this i dont know if it is a good algorithm or fast but i wants to tell all the newbies that its the easiest way to find 2nd largest element in the array.

```
            int[] arr = new int[8];
            int secondlarge;
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Index - {0} :", i);
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elemnts in array are: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i]);
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            temp = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > temp)
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    
                }

            }
            secondlarge = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (temp == arr[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (arr[i] > secondlarge)
                {
                    secondlarge = arr[i];
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Second Largest Number is : " + secondlarge);
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sort the array and arr[1] is the 2nd largest???

Comment: Does this code work or not? What output do you get? Do you just want people here to do a code review for you?

Comment: `new List<int>{ 1,5,53,4,2, 16 }.OrderbyDescending(i => i).Skip(1).First();`

Comment: you could actually do it in 1 loop and one complete iteration over the array. Before writing the new maximum to the `temp` variable remember the previous maximum and write it to `secondlarge = temp;`. that should do it. and you get O(n)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the `max` item and the next one:

```
int max = Math.Max(arr[0], arr[1]);
int result = Math.Min(arr[0], arr[1]);

for (int i = 2; i < arr.Length; ++i) 
  if (arr[i] >= max) 
    (result, max) = (max, arr[i]);
  else if (arr[i] > result)
    result = arr[i];
```

This approach can help in case of *long* `arr`: it's a bit faster then sorting (`O(n)` vs. `O(n * log(n))`) and doesn't require additional memory for sorted data (in case of Linq `OrderByDescending`)